# best practice: python run forever background process with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, asynchronous

Need a multi layer program in python, is this adviced:

> A) main loop must run forever
>
> |   postgresql db with a table to
> exchange data between  A and B
>
> B) django to serve content

A) perform some specialized tasks and sometime needs data that are coming from B) and reverse. But B must not wait for A to complete jobs.

is this ok or there are better ways?

Comment: I think you need to look at rabbitmq, dont write this by hand youre going to mess it up. Way smarter people then you and i have solved these issues for us, all we need is to use it.

Comment: thanks for the advice! I will look on it... I've found also django-q that look young but interensing, would you suggest to start with this or try celery with rabbitmq?

Comment: Celery with rabbitmq, there are thousands of suggestions/tutorials online! Just need to use google ;)

Comment: While RabbitMQ and Celery will do the job and do it very well, there is a much simpler solution that just uses redis. rpush and lpop this can be setup with minimal effort and django has great support for redis.